# Angular 2 RC5 Cannot match any routes: 'documents'

Tags: angular

I am in the process of upgrading my app to RC5 and have run into some difficulties.

In my app.routing.ts, I have:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'  },
{ path: 'home',  loadChildren: './app/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
{ path: 'documents',  loadChildren: './app/documents/documents.module#DocumentsModule' },
{ path: 'food',  loadChildren: './app/food/food.module#FoodModule' },
{ path: 'themes',  loadChildren: './app/themes/themes.module#ThemesModule' },
{ path: 'about',  loadChildren: './app/about/about.module#AboutModule' }];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here are the router links:

```
getLoggedInMenu() {
    return [
   {
      label: 'Home',
      routerLink: ['']
   }, {
      label: 'Documents',
      routerLink: ['/documents']
   }, {
      label: 'Tools',
      Items: [
      {
         label: 'Food',
         routerLink: ['/food']
      }, {
         label: 'Themes',
         routerLink: ['/themes']
      } ]
   },
   {
     label: 'About',
     routerLink: ['/about']
   }];
}
```

In food.routing.ts:

```
import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import {FoodComponent} from './food.component';

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'food', component: FoodComponent}]);
```

In themes.routing.ts:

```
import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import {ThemesComponent} from './themes.component';

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild([
{ path: 'themes', component: ThemesComponent}]);
```

These 2 routes work fine. However these 2 routes do not:

In document.routing.ts:

```
import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import {DocumentsComponent} from './documents.component';

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild([
 { path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent}]);
```

Error: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'documents'

In about.routing.ts:

```
import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './about.component';

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}]);
```

Error: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'about'

Each of the app directories are the same.  Each contains:

name.component.ts
name.component.css
name.component.html
name.module.ts
name.routing.ts

and the contents of each are the same except for the names.

Anybody see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of machinations, I noticed that the app.module.ts had imports for the working module routing and the ones that failed weren't there.  Importing them and adding them to the app.module imports section fixed the problem and all routes are now working.

Comment: I tried this. But doing so loads the imported modules when the application starts... which makes the app work but defeat the goal of dynamic loading of the component. Isn't it ? Did you come arround this ? Can you share your experience?